# Automatic file upload on browser request

Tags: node.js, http, nestjs

everyone!
This might be a silly question, but I want to understand how requesting a file from the frontend can automatically start uploading it after the backend has found it and given it away. I mean how to tell the browser that I'm submitting a file and have it start downloading

Right now I'm reading the file using node.js(using nest.js):

```
@Injectable()
export class FileService {
    constructor(
        private httpService: HttpService,
        private configService: ConfigService,
    ) {}

    download(request: Request, response: Response) {
        const mainGatewayUrl = this.configService.get('Endpoints.MainGatewayUrl')
        const { access } = this.configService.get('TokenKeys')
        const token = request.cookies[access] || ''

        const headers = {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            Cookie: request.headers.cookie || '',
            Accept: '*/*',
        }

        return this.httpService
            .request({
                method: request.method as Method,
                headers,
                responseType: 'arraybuffer',
                url: `${mainGatewayUrl}${request.params[0]}`,
                data: request.body,
            })
            .pipe(map((result) => response.send(result.data)))
    }
```

This is what ends up coming back to the browser in the response

[image]

and then in the browser I use this code to upload the file

[image]

All I want is to remove the extra code to run in the browser

Comment: How about `location.href = 'path to pdf file'` or `window.open('path to pdf file')` ? You can return a [`Content-Disposition` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) to set the filename from the backend.

Comment: Also, it's very confusing what you wrote, I'm assuming whenever you wrote "upload" you actually meant "download".